# Could not load file or assembly when run an exe from C# code

Tags: c#, .net

I have an executable file named MyExe and runs perfectly in CMD, but when I run it C#, something wrong happened:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Common, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cef71ad57bad51d2' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. at MyExe.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

This is my code to run exe file.

```
 try
 {
     Process process = new Process();
     process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
     process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     process.StartInfo.FileName = exec;
     process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

     if (args != null)
     {
         for (int idx = 0; idx < args.Length; ++idx)
         {
             if (idx == 0) process.StartInfo.Arguments = args[idx];
             else process.StartInfo.Arguments += " " + args[idx];
         }
     }
     Console.WriteLine(process.StartInfo.Arguments);
     process.Start();
     process.WaitForExit();
     Console.WriteLine("Complete!");
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
 }
```

I also tried run the exe file in C++ code, the output is correct.

Is there anything different when run an executable file in C#?

BTW, I don't have the source code of the exe file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you running both exe's from the same directory?

Comment: The environmental variable aren't set when you run as a process so you need to include full path names of files.  You could run as cmd.exe with you filename as an arguement.

Comment: It could always be a permission issue, try running Visual Studio as administrator

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins I tried, it doesn't work.

Comment: @TamásSzabó I run visual studio in administrator and the same things happened...

Comment: Are you running it from a local directory? You could get errors in C# when running from a network drive that you wouldn't in native code like C++

Comment: Thanks a lot! I solve the problem after I move all the related file to local directory.

Comment: Again thanks to all of you! @AlexanderHiggins

Comment: Again thanks to all of you! @jdweng

Comment: Again thanks to all of you! @TamásSzabó

Comment: NP, I added it as answer. You can mark it correct so others who read this will know what the issue was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are running the code from a local directory. You could get errors in C# when running from a network drive that you wouldn't in native code like C++.